# Serve MediaWiki Translate subpages from different subdomains with a single installation with Apache

Tags: .htaccess, mediawiki

I'm running a mediawiki installation with a "nice" URL htaccess to show https://example.com/Wiki/Page

I'd like to enable localization and translation on subdomains.

I'm thinking https://fr.example.com/Wiki/Page displays content from https://example.com/Wiki/Page/fr, and https://fr.example.com/Wiki/Page2 displays content from https://example.com/Wiki/Page2/fr

I think that should be achievable with `.htaccess`, but I'm not a mediawiki expert. Is there anyone out there that can help with enabling mediawiki translations on a subdomain like the above? I think it's just an `.htaccess` question, but not sure what it might break with mediawiki too :)

Comment: So you want to use only the Translate extension and have all content in a single wiki? But then make it viewable from different subdomains? Or will you have a separate wiki for each language?

Comment: I was hoping to just have one installation of mediawiki and make the different languages available via subdomains, but I'm not sure what best practice would be. Maybe it's simpler to have a separate media wiki installation for each language on a separate subdomain.